# Laravel - Execute function before query is fired

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, data-warehouse

is there a way for Eloquent/raw queries to execute a function before a query is fired? It would also be nice if I could extend the functionality to pass a parameter if the function should be run before or not. Depending on the outcome of the function (true/false) the query shouldn't be executed.

I would be nice to use the principal of "`DB::listen`", but I'm not sure if I can stop or run the query from within this function.

The reason for this is that I would like to build a little data warehouse myself for permanently saving results to a warehouse (db) and not query a huge database all the time.

The method I'm would like to use is to create a hash of a query, check if the hash exists in the warehouse. If it exists, then the value is returned. If not the query is executed and the output is saved together with the hash into the warehouse.

Any ideas?

///// EDIT /////
I should clarify, that I would like to access the queries and update the value if the calculated value needs to be updated. i.e.: Number of cars in december: While I'm in december, I need to keep updating the value every so often. So I store the executed query in the db and just retrieve it, run it and then update the value.

//// EDIT 2 /////
[image]

Github: https://github.com/khwerhahn/datawarehouselibrary/blob/master/DataWareHouseLib.php

What I would like to achieve is to hook into Laravels query/Eloquent logic and use the data warehouse logic in the background.

Maybe something like this:

```
$invalid_until = '2014-12-31 23:59:59'; // date until query needs to be updated every ten minutes
$cars = Cars::where('sales_month', '=', 12)->dw($invalid_until)->get();
```

If the dw($date_parameter) is added I would like Laravel to execute the data warehouse logic in the background and if found in the db then not execute the query again.

Comment: So basically you want a caching system. That's already in laravel by the way, besides the other packages you can find

Comment: Yes I would like a caching system, but a system that can persist queries with their result in a database, not just for 10 minutes

Comment: use `rememberForever()` if you don't want the cache to end, I don't know why you thought the cache limit is just 10 minutes

Comment: I should clarify that I might need to update the value every so often.. see edit

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use events to accomplish this. From the 4.2 docs:

> ## Caching Queries
>
> You may easily cache the results of a query using the remember method:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::table('users')->remember(10)->get();
> ```
>
> In this example, the results of the query will be cached for ten
>   minutes. While the results are cached, the query will not be run
>   against the database, and the results will be loaded from the default
>   cache driver specified for your application.
>
> http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#caching-queries

You can also use this for Eloquent objects,

eg: `User::where($condition)->remember(60)->get()`

Comment: This solution has a time limit though, but I want to persist them permanetly to a database

Comment: Just use `->rememberForever()` then

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're trying to do, but as I view it (I might not still be getting it right, though) you *still* can get away with using `rememberForever()` (if you don't want a specific time limit)

So, let's pretend you have a Cars table.

```
$cars = Cars::where('sales_month', '=', 12)->rememberForever()->get();
```

To work around the problem of deleting the cache, you can assign a key to the caching method, and then retrievit by that key. Now, the above query becomes:

```
$cars = Cars::where('sales_month', '=', 12)->rememberForever('cars')->get();
```

Every time you run that query you will be getting the same results, first time from the DB, all the others from the cache.

Now you say you're going to update the table, and you want to reset the cache, right?
So, run your update, then forget() the Cache with the `cars` index:

```
// Update query
Cache::forget('cars');
```

Your next call to the Cars query will issue a new resultset, and it will be cached. In case you're wondering, the `remember()` and `rememberForever()` are methods of the QueryBuilder class that use the same Cache class you can see in the docs in its own section.

Alternatively, in fact, you could also use the Cache class directly (it gives you a better control):

```
if (null == $cars= Cache::get('cars')) {
   $cars = Cars::where('sales_month', '=', 12)->get();
   Cache::forever('cars', $cars);
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but I would like to go a bit further. See edit

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the method runSelect exsists in Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder that runs in every select query in Laravel.

see this package:
https://github.com/TheGeekyM/caching-queries